# MySQL/PHP - Saving the coordinate of the chosen google map location

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

is there anyway where I can click on the google map then I can save it to MySQL using PHP, the coordinate then use it to display? I'm stuck on just using a coordinate to display it on the page using `<iframe>`

**EDIT**
Im using a `<form>` to save the data, then have a section where a google map is set to a certain location. When the user clicks on a precise coordinate, that coordinate is save and can be use again to display.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hello, I've edited my question. Thank you

Comment: The question is still way too broad and there are a number of approaches for solving the problem. Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps by filling in form fields based on the event click listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    // Then do something like this to fill in your form elements 
    document.getElementById("mylatbox").value = latitude;
    document.getElementById("mylongbox").value = longitude;


});
```

Comment: You could use AJAX pointed to some PHP processing with no form needed.